# Wordpress images not displaying after duplicating site

Tags: wordpress

I am redoing a wordpress site and I am having an issue with the images not displaying.

it is using a gallery that the images actually showup in the wordpress content admin section, but not on site.

click through and the image shows up ie: http://52.26.166.69/www.teamnutztechnology.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/text-friendly.jpg

could anyone help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: http://52.26.166.69/www.teamnutztechnology.com/wordpress/index.php/car-services/bluetooth/

Comment: http://teamnutztechnology.com/car-services/bluetooth/

Comment: Solved? I don't see any images not show? Please explain more: Your new site? Where images not show?

Comment: if you go to those two websites you will see the second one has the images (which is the original site it was copied from) and the first one doesnt

Comment: `/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/authorize_net_logo.jpg` This file already exist on your `teamnutztechnology.com`?

Comment: yes, and like i said it show fine in the admin section see here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx38FFwehf2gai1iUDNZaWNGQ3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try to use this plugin `regenerate-thumbnails`. If it not work. Try write 'some-things-for-test' If it's not show to your page => This mean you working on wrong page.